Est-ce que 'quoi' dans cette phrase est un pronom relatif indéfini ?
Je lis dans un texte de présentation de Propos sur le bonheur (Alain):

[...] car on voudrait s'assurer que l'existence est bonne et on ne le peut ; on en déçoit donc l'espérance par précaution, prononçant qu'elle est mauvaise. De là s'étend l'empire de l'imagination déréglée, en quoi Alain, se confiant à la sagesse du corps, restaure la souveraineté claire de l'homme heureux et qui n'attend pas pour l'être, ici et non ailleurs, que l'événement lui donne raison, acteur enfin et non spectateur de soi-même.

Est-ce que 'quoi' dans cette phrase est un pronom relatif indéfini ?

J'ai beau lire et relire ces lignes, j'avoue avoir du mal à en appréhender les subtilités.

@jlliagre Je peux proposer une interprétation si nécessaire, je crois comprendre.

Je ne suis pas 100% sûr du sens, mais grammaticalement je comprends la phrase comme ça :

De là s'étend l'empire de l'imagination déréglée, en quoi Alain [...] restaure la souveraineté [...]


Alain restaure la souveraineté en l'empire de l'imagination déréglée.

J'ai un léger doute parce que en n'est pas la préposition la plus courante pour parler de souveraineté (on utilisera plutôt de ou sur), mais je ne vois d'autre interprétation pour le moment.

Je suis d'accord, je lis ce en comme un dans. En se concentrant sur le moment présent par l'intermédiaire de la conscience du corps, Alain restaure la souveraineté de l'homme qui peut agir (par son corps), plutôt que de se laisser aller à son imagination, qu'il utilise pour faire face à son existence malheureuse.

Le Wiktionnaire considère "en quoi" comme une locution conjonctive équivalente à "en cela": "quoi" est donc pronom, à fonction plutôt démonstrative que relative. Que remplace ce pronom? Simplifions la citation et substituons:

Par précaution, on déçoit l'espérance que la vie soit
bonne. De là s'étend l'empire de l'imagination déréglée,
en cela Alain restaure la souveraineté de l'homme heureux.

"Cela" désigne donc, comme le lieu "là" (le point duquel s'étend l'empire), les phrases qui précèdent: tout le cheminement intellectuel qui {casse | abolit | lézarde | compromet d'aucune manière exigeant restauration} la souveraineté de l'homme heureux.
Sur quoi s'exerce cette souveraineté? Le texte cité n'en dit rien et, contrairement à Teleporting Goat, je crois que le lecteur n'est pas censé le deviner. En tous cas, cette question est hors sujet par rapport au problème initial, qui est la fonction grammaticale de "quoi".
Alors? Pronom, certainement. Pronom relatif? Bof, je l'analyse plutôt comme un pronom démonstratif.
Si vraiment c'est un pronom relatif, son antécédent est "là", si tant est qu'un adverbe puisse être antécédent; sinon, il coïncide avec ce que "là" désigne et que j'ai tenté d'expliciter ci-dessus.

Soueraineté sur l'empire de l'imagination déréglée.

C'est une possibilité, et manifestement il existe un lecteur qui le croit. En voici une autre: souveraineté sur le jardin du philosphe.

OK, mais pourquoi dis-tu cela? C'est peut-être ce que pense Alain, mais ce ne peut pas être ce à quoi se rapporte ce en quoi dans cet extrat de ce texte tel que présenté - ce serait incompréhensible tel quel, l'inférence est trop loin du texte car le jardin du philosophe est une notion que cet extrait de ce texte ne mentionne pas du tout.

Le passage en fait commence par: Voici le jardin du philosophe. On y cueillera des fruits mûris sur le tronc de la sagesse commune et dorés à cette autre lumière des idées. Ils en reprennent leur saveur d'origine, qui est le goût de l'existence. Saveur oubliée en nos pensées ; car on voudrait s'assurer que l'existence est bonne et on ne le peut ;... mais même en restaurant cette partie du texte, le jardin du philosophe est toujours trop loin de ce en quoi qui a besoin d'un référent plus proche, à mon avis.
